# Terraform Error | A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am getting below error for `terraform plan`

```
│ Error: Invalid reference
│ 
│   on main.tf line 107, in resource "null_resource" "health":
│  107:         gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --zone=${zone} --flatten="metadata[]" >> ${self.triggers.health_report}
│ 
│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

Following is the terraform code:

```
resource "null_resource" "health" {
  count = local.num_instances
  triggers = {
        health_report = "${path.module}/health.txt"
  }  

  provisioner "local-exec" {
  when = create
  command = <<-EOT
        zone=$(gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --format="value(zone)") && \ 
        while gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --flatten="metadata[]" | grep -q am_i_healthy ; do 
           sleep 5 
        done
        gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --zone=${zone} --flatten="metadata[]" >> ${self.triggers.health_report}
       EOT
    on_failure = fail
    environment = {
      TF_LOG = "DEBUG"
    }
```

I am already using instance name, so no clue as to why I am getting the error. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The line of code that Terraform indicated in the error message includes a reference to `zone`.

Terraform thinks that you are intending to refer to a resource of type `zone` -- that is, something you might hypothetically declare with a `resource "zone" "example"` block -- and so the error message is written with that assumption in mind.

In practice I suspect you intended some other interpretation, but either way the problem is that `zone` is not a symbol that's in scope in this context.

Referring to the rest of your script I see that you declared a shell variable called `zone` and so presumably you were intending to refer to that. Since your shell uses a similar interpolation syntax as Terraform you will need to escape the interpolation to avoid Terraform trying to evaluate it before the underlying shell does:

```
    command = <<-EOT
      zone=$(gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --format="value(zone)") && \
      while ! gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --zone=${zone} --flatten="metadata[]" | grep -q am_i_healthy ; do
         sleep 5
      done
      gcloud compute instances describe ${google_compute_instance_from_template.compute_instance[count.index].name} --project=${local.project_id} --zone=$${zone} --flatten="metadata[]" >> ${path.module}/health.txt
     EOT
```

The sequence `$${zone}` is, in [Terraform's string template syntax](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates), the [escape sequence](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences-1) for a literal `${`. Therefore Terraform will replace `$${zone}` with `${zone}` as part of rendering the template, and then your shell will hopefully replace `${zone}` with the defined value of that shell variable.